# extract and convert date as character

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

how can I extract date and convert it to a 3 letter character ? What I am trying to approach is a column with 3 letter month as in my local local language. The code I am trying is giving me an error:

```
SELECT 
DATE,
CASE
WHEN (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE))= CAST(1 AS CHAR(3)) THEN CAST('JAN' AS CHAR(3))
WHEN (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE))=CAST(2 AS CHAR(3)) THEN CAST('FEV' AS CHAR(3))
WHEN (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE))=CAST(3 AS CHAR(3)) THEN CAST('MAR' AS CHAR(3))
WHEN (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE))=CAST(4 AS CHAR(3)) THEN CAST('ABR' AS CHAR(3))
END
AS MONTH,
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: If you get an error, then please post the actual error in your question. Although if I have to guess, you get a "Token unknown" error as `DATE` is a reserved word

Comment: I would suggest you use the open source `DateToStr()`1 function described on this FAQ:  http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq314/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query as shown is your actual query, then you get an error "Token unknown" as `DATE` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an identifier without explicitly quoting. Either rename your column (highly advisable), or use `"DATE"` instead of `DATE` in your query.

The return value of `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM somedate)` is an integer, not a `CHAR(3)`, so the cast in `(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATE))= CAST(1 AS CHAR(3))` will cause additional overhead as Firebird will need to convert the result of `EXTRACT` from integer to string to evaluate the condition. Instead, you should use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "DATE") = 1`.

Your code can be simplified by using a [*searched* case](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-case-srched) as this avoids repeated extraction:

```
CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM "DATE")
  WHEN 1 THEN 'JAN'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'FEV'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'MAR'
  -- ... etc
END
```

Character literals are already `CHAR` (`CHAR(3)` in this case), so casting is unnecessary. But if you really need to cast, then I suggest putting the cast around the entire `CASE ... END`, and not around the individual values in the `THEN` clauses.

If you want to further condense this, you could also use the [`DECODE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-decode) function:

```
DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM "DATE"), 1, 'JAN', 2, 'FEV', 3, 'MAR' /* ... etc */)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, if I try DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM PEDDTEMIS),1,'JAN') it doesn' work , it gives me an error message that it cannot convert the data type, but if I do DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM PEDDTEMIS),1,1) it works. Any idea ?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: Hi, currently 2.5

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull And the exact version? It works fine for me in 2.5.8.

Comment: guess this `DECODE` can be encapsulated into a `computed field`. That would be both easier to use (no need to copy-paste it into different queries) and future-safe for possible extensions (like, adding into the database a dedicated table with month names for several different languages)

Comment: @Arioch'The Sounds like a good idea, or - in Firebird 3 - in a PSQL function for easier reuse.

Comment: It worked with the DECODE solution. For some reason I got error messages in another query but I have tried in a new one and it worked. Tks

Answer (score -2):

On oracle you can use to_char function;

select to_char( sysdate,'mon','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE =English') as month from dual

Instead of English you can provide 'your local language', if your sessions default language is already in your desired language then no need for 3rd parameter, this will be enough;

select to_char( sysdate,'mon') as month from dual

Comment: This question is about Firebird, not about Oracle.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how you can do it in firebird
but you can do it in microsoft sql server like below:

```
SELECT 
DATE,
CASE 
when DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE])=1 THEN CAST('JAN' AS CHAR(3))
when DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE])=2 THEN CAST('FEV' AS CHAR(3))
when DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE])=3 THEN CAST('MAR' AS CHAR(3))
end
from YourTable
```

Comment: This question is about Firebird, not about SQL Server